# Get an image from storage using image path and without using image picker in react native

Tags: android, react-native, local-storage, imagepicker

I think i have an interesting question and i was curious whether there is a way to do it or not. I was searching a way to pick and image using only image path like you do it in windows you just give the path and get the image or any other file. But for android and react native i searched for a whole day and couldn't find a way do it. Every approach was pointing towards opening the gallery and manually picking the image using image picker.
So anyone know or is it even possible to get an image or file by using only it's path from local storage in android react native?

Comment: I see no reason that it was not posible. If you know the path and the path is readable you can load the image.

Comment: It is not that simple. I tried but apparently, you need permission to access the local storage after getting permission from the user you can only import the image in the app using an image picker. The only way I figured out to do this is to include the picture inside the app directory then can access it with just the file path. but if I start including the images in-app directly then it will increase the apk size of the application. which I can not afford to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.